# Finding a mode with decreasing precision

Tags: java, algorithm, statistics, mode

I feel like there should be an available library to more simply do two things, A) Find the mode to an array, in the case of doubles and B) gracefully degrade the precision until you reach a particular frequency.

So imagine an array like this:

```
double[] a = {1.12, 1.15, 1.13, 2.0, 3.4, 3.44, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4};
```

If I was looking for a frequency of 3 then it would go from 2 decimal positions to 1 decimal, and finally return 1.1 as my mode.  If I had a frequency requirement of 4 it would return 4 as my mode.

I do have a set of code that is working the way I want, and returning what I am expecting, but I feel like there should be a more efficient way to accomplish this, or an existing library that would help me do the same.  Attached is my code, I'd be interested in thoughts / comments on different approaches I should have taken....I have the iterations listed to limit how far  the precision can degrade.

```
public static double findMode(double[] r, int frequencyReq)
{
    double mode = 0d;
    int frequency = 0;
    int iterations = 4;

    HashMap<Double, BigDecimal> counter = new HashMap<Double, BigDecimal>();

    while(frequency < frequencyReq && iterations > 0){
        String roundFormatString = "#.";
        for(int j=0; j<iterations; j++){
            roundFormatString += "#";
        }
        DecimalFormat roundFormat = new DecimalFormat(roundFormatString);
        for(int i=0; i<r.length; i++){

            double element = Double.valueOf(roundFormat.format(r[i]));

            if(!counter.containsKey(element))
                counter.put(element, new BigDecimal(0));

            counter.put(element,counter.get(element).add(new BigDecimal(1)));
        }

        for(Double key : counter.keySet()){

            if(counter.get(key).compareTo(new BigDecimal(frequency))>0){
                mode = key;
                frequency = counter.get(key).intValue();
                log.debug("key: " + key + " Count: " + counter.get(key));
            }
        }
        iterations--;
    }

    return mode;
}
```

**Edit**

Another way to rephrase the question, per Paulo's comment: the goal is to locate a number where in the neighborhood are at least `frequency` array elements, with the radius of the neighborhood being as small as possible.

Comment: Only to be clear, the *mode* is the most often element, yeah?

Comment: Correct, though I realize technically once I start dropping precision it isn't EXACTLY the mode, rather an approximation.

Comment: So we search a number where in the neighbourhood are at least `frequency` array elements, with the radius of the neighborhood being as small as possible. Could this be a reformulation of the problem?

Comment: @Paulo, yes, I think that  would be a good way to rephrase it.  I'll edit that into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution to the reformulated question:

> The goal is to locate a number where in the neighborhood are at least `frequency` array elements, with the radius of the neighborhood being as small as possible.

(I took the freedom of switching the order of `1.15` and `1.13` in the input array.)

The basic idea is: We have the input already sorted (i.e. neighboring elements are consecutive), and we know how many elements we want in our neighborhood. So we loop once over this array, measuring the distance between the left element and the element `frequency` elements more to the right. Between them are `frequency` elements, so this forms a neighbourhood. Then we simply take the minimum such distance. (My method has a complicated way to return the results, you may want to do it better.)

This is not completely equivalent to your original question (does not work by fixed steps of digits), but maybe this is more what you really want :-)

You'll have to find a better way of formatting the results, though.

```
package de.fencing_game.paul.examples;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * searching of dense points in a distribution.
 *
 * Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329628/finding-a-mode-with-decreasing-precision.
 */
public class InpreciseMode {

    /** our input data, should be sorted ascending. */
    private double[] data;

    public InpreciseMode(double ... data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    /**
     * searchs the smallest neighbourhood (by diameter) which
     * contains at least minSize elements.
     *
     * @return an array of two arrays:
     *     {   { the middle point of the neighborhood,
     *           the diameter of the neighborhood  },
     *        all the elements of the neigborhood }
     *
     * TODO: better return an object of a class encapsuling these.
     */
    public double[][] findSmallNeighbourhood(int minSize) {
        int currentLeft = -1;
        int currentRight = -1;
        double currentMinDiameter = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

        for(int i = 0; i + minSize-1 < data.length; i++) {
            double diameter = data[i+minSize-1] - data[i];
            if(diameter < currentMinDiameter) {
                currentMinDiameter = diameter;
                currentLeft = i;
                currentRight = i + minSize-1;
            }
        }
        return
            new double[][] {
            { 
                (data[currentRight] + data[currentLeft])/2.0,
                currentMinDiameter
            },
            Arrays.copyOfRange(data, currentLeft, currentRight+1)
        };
    }

    public void printSmallNeighbourhoods() {
        for(int frequency = 2; frequency <= data.length; frequency++) {
            double[][] found = findSmallNeighbourhood(frequency);

            System.out.printf("There are %d elements in %f radius "+
                              "around %f:%n     %s.%n",
                              frequency, found[0][1]/2, found[0][0],
                              Arrays.toString(found[1]));
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] params) {
        InpreciseMode m =
            new InpreciseMode(1.12, 1.13, 1.15, 2.0, 3.4, 3.44, 4.1,
                              4.2, 4.3, 4.4);
        m.printSmallNeighbourhoods();
    }

}
```

The output is

```
There are 2 elements in 0,005000 radius around 1,125000:
     [1.12, 1.13].
There are 3 elements in 0,015000 radius around 1,135000:
     [1.12, 1.13, 1.15].
There are 4 elements in 0,150000 radius around 4,250000:
     [4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4].
There are 5 elements in 0,450000 radius around 3,850000:
     [3.4, 3.44, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3].
There are 6 elements in 0,500000 radius around 3,900000:
     [3.4, 3.44, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4].
There are 7 elements in 1,200000 radius around 3,200000:
     [2.0, 3.4, 3.44, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4].
There are 8 elements in 1,540000 radius around 2,660000:
     [1.12, 1.13, 1.15, 2.0, 3.4, 3.44, 4.1, 4.2].
There are 9 elements in 1,590000 radius around 2,710000:
     [1.12, 1.13, 1.15, 2.0, 3.4, 3.44, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3].
There are 10 elements in 1,640000 radius around 2,760000:
     [1.12, 1.13, 1.15, 2.0, 3.4, 3.44, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4].
```

Comment: That is a really neat way to formulate this, @Paŭlo!  Now its time to take your approach and my initial approach and benchmark them!

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing wrong with your code and I doubt that you will find a library that does something so specific. But if still you want an idea to approach this problem using a more OOP approach that reuses Java collections, here it comes another approach:

- Create a class to represent numbers with different number of decimals. It would have something like `VariableDecimal(double d,int ndecimals)` as constructor.
- In that class override the object methods `equals` and `hashCode`. Your implementation of `equals` will test if two instances of `VariableDecimal` are the same taking into account the value `d` and the number of decimals. `hashCode` can simple return `d*exp(10,ndecimals)` casted to Integer.

In your logic use `HashMaps` so that they reuse your object:

```
HashMap<VariableDecimal, AtomicInteger> counters = new HashMap<VariableDecimal, AtomicInteger>();
for (double d : a) {
     VariableDecimal vd = new VariableDecimal(d,ndecimals);
     if (counters.get(vd)!=null)
         counters.set(vd,new AtomicInteger(0));
     counters.get(vd).incrementAndGet();

}
/* at the end of this loop counters should hold a map with frequencies of 
   each double for the selected precision so that you can simply traverse and 
   get the max */
```

This piece of code doesn't show the iteration to decrement the number of decimals, which is trivial.